# How can I determine in Go if the connection to a stream is broken?

Tags: go

The following code listens to a stream.

```
func listen() {
  conn, err := net.Dial("udp", "127.0.0.1:10001")
  checkError(err)

  conn.Write([]byte("PROCEED"))

  for {
    s := make([]byte, 1024)
    conn.Read(s)
    data := string(s)

    if len(data) > 0 {
      go processData(data)
    } else {
      fmt.Println("No bytes received!!!")
    }
  }
}
```

How can I know in the for loop if my connection is broken?

Comment: UDP isn't a stream, so there's nothing to be "broken". You also should not use buffered IO on a udp connection, since you need to be incontrol of the individual read size for the datagrams.

Comment: I've changed the script above. Is there any way to determine if I terminate my UDP server on the other side?

Comment: No. UDP is a series of unrelated datagrams. There's no "connection" to detect being closed or broken. You need another protocol for that, which is usually TCP.